# rosbag play & tf static_transform_publisher

Tags: ros, geometry, rosbag, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've recorded some data and realized one of my static transforms was wrong. Specifically, I'm want to run robot_pose_ekf, but my /base_footprint to /imu transform is upside down.

I want to play back the data with a new transform, provided by tf's static_transform_publisher node. But this doesn't work because the data's time is in the past, and transform's time is in the present. Is it possible to have static_transform_publisher broadcast in the past? Or is there something else I can do?

To clarify, I get warnings that look like this:

> [ WARN] [1297969705.023576238]: You
> requested a transform that is
> 75418.058 seconds in the past, but the tf buffer only has a history of 10.685
> seconds.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9106/rosbag-play-&-tf-static_transform_publisher/) by [tperkins](https://answers.ros.org/users/124/tperkins/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2011-02-17

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-02-17**:
when you see an answer you like, mark it as an accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the tf_remap script to filter the output of your bag file.  See the [tf wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf#tf_remap)

To use it you will want to remap your playback to put /tf onto /old_tf and then use tf_remap to move most things from /old_tf to /tf with your remappings applied.

To deal with the timing issue you should set [use_sim_time parameter](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Clock) and playback the bag file with the [clock option](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Commandline#play) enabled.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2